# Are there any guarantees that static initialization will not overwrite the value from explicit initialization?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following two variables, both statically initialized, and they live in different compilation units.

Foo.cc

```
Foo foo;
```

Bar.cc

```
Bar bar;
```

Suppose that, ordinarily `bar` is statically initialized after `foo`.

If the constructor of foo was written to write the value of `bar`, is there is a chance that the subsequent static initialization of `bar` would overwrite the value written by `foo?`

That is, assuming `Bar` has a second constructor which takes a string, and the constructor for `foo` looks like this:

```
Foo::Foo() {
   bar = Bar("Hello World");
    /// do other stuff to make a Foo
}
```

Is there any chance that the static initialization for `bar` will run after `foo` and overwrite the value of `bar` written by `foo`'s constructor?

Comment: using `const Bar bar;` maybe??

Comment: When bar static initializes, it won't check if it's already been initialized, it'll just do its thing. So yes, there's a chance, it's proportional to the sum of {how inconvenient the day/hour is, how drunk you are, how tired you are, how likely your are to be excommunicated from your family if you take the call just now}.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18140733/179910).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott Meyers said:

> [...]  the relative order of initialization of non-local static objects defined in different translation units is undefined. [...]

and:

> Fortunately, a small design change eliminates the problem entirely. All that has to be done is to move each non-local static object into its own function, where it's declared static. These functions return references to the objects they contain. Clients then call the functions instead of referring to the objects. In other words, non-local static objects are replaced with local static objects. (Aficionados of design patterns will recognize this as a common implementation of the Singleton pattern.)

As an example of this working can be looked at: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use-members.html

Comment: I tried this approach and it added 0.7 ms to what was previous a 5 ms latency in a highly latency-sensitive application.

Comment: My guess is that wrapping inside a function with static may be equivalent to forcing a branch every time a condition is called.

Comment: @merlin2011 You can avoid this kind of solution, putting guards into sensitive objects to ensure the order of initialization. For example, if foo depends of bar, put a guard in bar telling if it is initialized or not. At foo initialization. test for this guard. If it is not initialized. initialized bar, otherwise, just initialize foo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *dynamic initialization* (which is what is happening when your static's constructors are invoked) could happen in any order.

If static objects need to depend on each other, it's best practice to dynamically allocate them on demand and protect the initialization so that it happens only once, similar to the singleton pattern.