# C++ static variable declaration - difference between module vs function

Tags: c++, scope, static, declaration

This is probably answered on the web somewhere, but I had trouble querying via search engine.

In order to adhere to the construct-on-first-use idiom, I have moved static object declaration from the module scope (top of the file) to within a local function that returns a reference, for each.  The idea being I can somewhat control the order things are constructed based on when those objects are first used.

What I'm trying to understand is what is the cost/benefit of one versus the other?  Are there any?

(These are not accessed via multiple threads)

Example:
Declared:
`static CLASS_T object1;`

Accessed:
`object1.Do();`

vs.

Declared:

```
    static CLASS_T & GetObject1()
    {
        static CLASS_T object1;
        return object1;
    }
```

Accessed:
`GetObject1().Do();`

Everything compiles fine, I just want to understand if there are tradeoffs or anything I'm not expecting that I should be aware of.

This post is related [Difference between Static variable declared in different scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140552/difference-between-static-variable-declared-in-different-scopes), but I'm curious if access via reference makes any difference, and if this is truly supporting the construct-on-first-use idiom.

Comment: This arrangement, if used consistently, eliminates the Static Initialization Order Fiasco.